# Make CXF Web Service work when there is no internet connection

Tags: java, spring, soap, xsd, cxf

I have a SOAP CXF Web Service which does not start when there is no internet connection.

Error when one of test was done is as follows

```
caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException (at /definitions/types/xs:schema/xsd:schema/schema): faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: Problem parsing 'file:/C:/<tomcat_instance>/webapps/cxfws/xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd'.: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.getDocument(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2198) ~[wsdl4j-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]
```

Found a link
https://users.cxf.apache.narkive.com/z0jMuziG/running-cxf-on-a-server-that-don-t-have-an-internet-connection
But the suggestion in that is not helping me to resolve the problem
Tried to define
spring.schemas under META-INF with the line
http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd=xsd/xmldsig-core-schema.xsd
But this is not helping out to resolve the problem.

Any suggestions?
Also what is the purpose of spring.handlers? Is this also required?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to resolve parsing error on startup of the product by removing wsdlLocation from cxf-beans.xml and also from the @javax.jws.WebService annotation in the SOAP service implementation class